# How can I check if a Windows account belongs to an AD group?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there any command or tool I can run from my desktop, not from AD server, that I can pass a Windows account and get a list of groups it belongs to?

Or pass a group and see the users it contains?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell solution using the [ActiveDirectory Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) and
using [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps) in particular to give you a list of all groups and nested groups a particular username is a member of from a Windows 10 client workstation.

## PowerShell (user membership)

```
$username = Read-Host "Enter username";
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | select @{Name="Primary Groups";Expression={$_."name"}};

$id = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]("$username");
$groups = $id.Groups | foreach-object {$_.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])};
$groups | select @{Name="All Groups (Including Nested)";Expression={$_."Value"}} | FT -AutoSize;
```

---

**Sample Output**

```
Primary Groups                                     
--------------                                     
Domain Users                                       
Organization Management                            
Domain Admins                                      
Schema Admins                                      
Enterprise Admins                                                                                 
IT                 

All Groups (Including Nested)                              
-----------------------------                              
<Domain>\Domain Users                                       
Everyone                                                                   
BUILTIN\Performance Log Users                              
BUILTIN\Users                                              
BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users                               
BUILTIN\Administrators                                     
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK                                       
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                           
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                             
<Domain>\Domain Admins
```

---

Here's another PowerShell solution using [Get-ADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) to get all members of a particular AD group from a Windows 10 client workstation.

## PowerShell (group members)

```
$group = Read-Host "Enter group name";
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | & {
    Process{ If($_.objectClass -eq "user"){$_.name}}
    }
```

---

## Supporting Resources

- [ActiveDirectory Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps)

  - [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps)
  - [Get-ADGroupMember](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps)

> You can install [ActiveDirectory Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) from Windows 10 by going to **Settings** |
> **Apps** | **Apps & Features** | click **Optional features** | click **Add a feature** |  type in "**RSAT**" and when you see [**RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services
> Toos**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RntFX.png) install it. You should see
> [both that and **RSAT: Server
> Manager**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qyU6.png) features installed once
> that completes and you can then use the AD PowerShell modules to query
> AD from the Windows 10 machine afterwards—a reboot might be
> needed after the install so keep that in mind as well.

Comment: @EdwinDev ... If you need the username to be an argument you pass to a script rather than for it to prompt for the username, let me know. That's just a trivial matter but I can help if that's what you need it to be. Otherwise, this will work passing the username to the script as an argument or specifying it via Read-Host or any other way you want to set the username to give you the result. If you need help with getting the ActiveDirectory modules installed on the Windows 10 client workstation, that too is just a trivial matter I can give you some guidance to accomplish if needed.